# How to make the BottomSheetFragment with multiple tabs height adjustable according to the height available in the currently selected tab?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting a weird bug, in which for the first time, the tab height is not getting adjusted according to the height of the currently selected tab when an action is performed inside the 2nd or 3rd tab like hiding a layout. Please help. Sharing the screenshot below.

The way it behaved currently on 1st time.

[image: Image with extra space at the bottom]

The way it behaved after I choose any other tab and came back to the same tab. It adjusts the height according to the content height and it works correctly after that onwards.

[image: Image with no space at the bottom]

Please download the source code in order to see the issue.

Repo link: https://github.com/chinmaydash007/Compose2022

Activity in which the dialog is present:
https://github.com/chinmaydash007/Compose2022/blob/master/visit/src/main/java/com/example/visit/activity/MainActivity.kt

Dialog name: SelectFilterBottomSheetFragment

Please use Android Studio Giraffe or higher if you are downloading the repo.